# OpenAES/OpenSSL compatibility

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I'm trying to use both OpenAES and OpenSSL in C, this way:

- Application 1 encodes a password using OpenAES
- Application 2 decodes the password using OpenSSL

The problem is that I can't decode it, actually I'm quite surprised as OpenAES generates a
different block each time when OpenSSL or any other AES implementation I've seen always generate
the same block.

Another difference I noticed is that the OpenAES generated block is 48 bytes, when OpenSSL generates 16.

This is how I encrypt the string (OpenAES):

```
  pCtx = oaes_alloc();
  if (pCtx == NULL)
    return FALSE;

  oRet = oaes_key_import(pCtx, sKey, szKey);
  if (oRet != OAES_RET_SUCCESS)
  {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // Get the required buffer size
  oRet = oaes_encrypt(pCtx, (const uint8_t*)csSource, szLen, NULL, pOutLen);
  if (oRet != OAES_RET_SUCCESS)
  {
    oaes_free(&pCtx);
    return FALSE;
  }

  *ppOut = (char*)calloc(*pOutLen, sizeof(char));
  oRet = oaes_encrypt(pCtx, (const uint8_t*)csSource, szLen, (uint8_t*)*ppOut, pOutLen);
  if (oRet != OAES_RET_SUCCESS)
  {
    oaes_free(&pCtx);
    free(*ppOut);
    return FALSE;
  }

  oaes_free(&pCtx);
```

And this is how I decrypt it (OpenSSL):

```
AES_KEY kDecrypt;

AES_set_decrypt_key(sKey, 128, &kDecrypt);
AES_decrypt(pEncoded, pDecoded, &kDecrypt);
```

**sKey** being the key generated with OpenAES
**pEncoded** the crypted block from OpenAES
**pDecoded** the output data.

I can't put my finger on the problem yet...

Is there a particular way to use OpenAES so the result can be decrypted by OpenSSL, or is it just not compatible?

Comment: I am puzzled why you are using `oaes_decrypt(...)` in your encryption code.  Is this just some horribly bad naming by OpenAES?

Comment: My bad, I had pasted the wrong code... thanks for noticing! I edited it.

Comment: Great library, no documentation, no issues. Can hardly be found by Googling, even if it is featured on Google code. And what about this snippet: `for( _j = 0; _j < OAES_BLOCK_SIZE - _block_size; _j++ ) {_block[ _block_size + _j ] = _j + 1;}` ? If that's padding, then what kind of padding would it be? Stay away from crap like this please.

Comment: I followed your advice and removed OpenAES from my project, I'll try another solution with OpenSSL after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OpenAES** prefixes the encrypted data with a OpenAES specific header, followed by the iv and then the encrypted data (+ padding).

As the IV seems to be generated randomly by OpenAES that explains why the data differs with each encrypt.

Comment: It's a undescribed proprietary format even with proprietary padding. If I find out which Eclipse dev is using it, I'm going to give him a good kicking.